# Sending POST requests to Google Action/API.AI or sending responses which take more than 5s

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

My fulfillment needs to do a lot of processing after receiving a certain request from Google Action/API.AI and the default response timeout is 5s.
https://developers.google.com/actions/components/fulfillment#nodejs

Is there any way I could send a delayed response or send a POST request after the results are ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no - you must respond within 5 seconds, and there is no way to send a notification back through the Assistant at this time.

The slightly longer answer is that we know notifications are coming - but we don't know if there will be an API for them. There have been rumors about other ways that may be coming that allow us to work around the 5 second limit.

The even longer answer is that, if you are using Action [Transactions](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/) (ie - allowing the user to purchase or reserve something) you can send updates after the fact. *However*, Transactions are still in developer preview and don't work on all surfaces (they don't work on Google Home at all, for example).